# Fetching Anyone's Friends

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to fetch any user's list of friends? In the facebook Graph API it is specified that we can fetch the friendlist by issuing an HTTP GET to /PROFILE_ID/friends.

When I tried that I got an error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported operation", 
    "type": "FacebookApiException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

Is such an operation allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, its not.

You can only look up the friends of the users who have authorized your app with 'read_friendlists' permission. You cant get the friendlist of other users even if their friendlist is public.Seems like FB is limiting this intentionally.

The Error code 100 means invalid parameter by the way. So, that says it is not possible.

Comment: 'read_friendlists' is used to manage the friend *lists*, that is the collection of friends such as acquaintances, close friends, etc. Basically, you need a special permission to see how the user decided to group their friends. On the contrary, it is possible to read the complete list of friends through the User api (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) and without a special permission. I also see the spurious "code=100" error, I don't know why it happens, but it's not related to an extra permission.

Comment: On the other hand, `mutualfriends` can still always be queried.

Comment: @ErikAllik Which doesn't really help, because its a subset of your friends. No way to expand the query beyond your own friends then...