# Facebook: Trust created app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I created a Facebook App on their developer page. When using the access_token generated by their Graph Explorer App (which I trusted) I can query stuff about myself and all is well.

Now that I have an App Token, I've tried using that instead of the one generated by Graph Explorer and it is not working (Doing the same thing as [Fetching Anyone's Friends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13552858/fetching-anyones-friends)).

How do I trust the new app I've created with querying my own account?

Answer (score 0):

As a stupid hack-around, you can go to the Graph Explorer app page, select your app from the list, and then hit "Get Access Token." This will add the app to your app page with the permissions you select, and you'll be golden.

Not sure how to get it to work for *other people* though, but I'll cross that bridge when I get there.